# Apple Magic Mouse 2 not scrolling

Tags: drivers, mouse

I'm on 20.04.3 and my kernal is 5.11.0-46-generic. A brief description of the issue: my Magic Mouse 2 works in the sense that left and right click both work, but scrolling does not work.

I've seen a few different answers on this, but most seem to point to [this](https://github.com/rohitpid/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver) github page. I've installed the driver as directed, restarted my machine, but my mouse still only does left and right clicks. The troubleshooting page says "**make sure that the correct hid-magicmouse driver gets loaded** and try the following steps". I'm not sure how to do the bolded version of what I quoted, but I followed the steps until I ran into the error "rmmod: ERROR: Module hid_magicmouse is not currently loaded".

It seems like my issue is not having the module loaded, but I'm also unsure how to do that. Can anyone assist? Thank you so much!

Edit: I've also read that it should've been folded into the newest version of Ubuntu, but I installed a fresh long term version today and then updated. (It's my first day on Linux ever so go easy on me :) )

Edit # 2: The github page I linked also mentioned that the issue has been addressed in a new kernal (5.15), which I explored but signing kernels is a bit out of my skillset at this moment and I don't want to mess up my installation.

Comment: The `rmmod` removes a module.  The error message is telling you there was nothing loaded to remove.  Looking at the instructions on the [link](https://github.com/rohitpid/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver) you referenced, it has you do an `insmod` (insert module) as the next step.  What were the results of that command?

Comment: @Bovine , the results of that command are "insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./hid-magicmouse.ko: Operation not permitted". I thought it might be a permissions issue so moved into root with "sudo so" but the same issue persists.

Comment: Did the earlier commands complete without error?  You might run `find hid-magicmouse.ko` to see where the make command put the module.  It should be in that directory listed in the `cd` command.

Comment: @Bovine yes, the base installation ran without error. When I go through the troubleshooting steps, I run into the same issue of "rmmod: Error: Module hid_magicmouse is not currently loaded". I was able to find the hid-magicmouse.ko module in "linux/drivers/hid/hid-magicmouse.ko" using the command you provided but perhaps I'm just not sure how to load it?

Comment: You can try `sudo insmod ./linux/drivers/hid/hid-magicmouse.ko middle_click_3finger=1
` to see if that works.  Otherwise you will probably need to reach out to the author of the github page for support.